# How to check IIS version on Azure Websites?

Tags: iis, azure

I can't find any information about IIS on my Azure Websites Dashboard. I checked every panel.

Answer (score 5):

You can see the IIS version and other server information in Kudu on the Environment page under the Server variables heading.

The variable name is SERVER_SOFTWARE, for example my web app has `SERVER_SOFTWARE=Microsoft-IIS/8.0`

To access Kudu, you can navigate to `https://[app-name].scm.azurewebsites.net`, or you can look for the Advanced Tools blade under Development Tools:

[image: Advanced Tools in the App Service side menu]

Answer (score 3):

This information is not available on the Dashboard.

You can simply use the Server Variable "SERVER_SOFTWARE" anywhere in your code:

```
ViewBag.Message = Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_SOFTWARE"];
```

[Here is the result on Azure Web Sites](https://double.azurewebsites.net/Home/About) in West Europe data centre.

Comment: As of this date of 2/22/2016, the value is `Microsoft-IIS/8.0`.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the IIS version is dependant on the OS Family / Server version you're using on instance.  This is very unqualified but I believe 2008 runs IIS 7, 2012 IIS 8 and [2012 R2 IIS 8.5](http://davidjrh.intelequia.com/2013/10/welcome-os-family-4-windows-server-2012.html).

Probably the simplest way is to deploy up a server, RDP into it and find out that way...

HTH

Comment: RDP on Azure Websites servers ? Sorry but how can I do that ?

Comment: If you're logging into a VM then use this -> http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-log-on-windows-server/ is a good starting point.  For a Cloud Service, follow this -> http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-configure/ and review the section on RemoteDesktop.

Comment: @SeanCocteau the user is asking about Ayure Web Sites, which is qutie different service from Cloud Services! And there is no remote desktop! And there is no OS choise for Web Sites!

Comment: @astakov Ah - well pointed out.  I tend to get muddled up with the explicit Azure Websites.  
Llm - Check out this article, can't say I've tried it myself though.  -> http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/02/28/remote-administration-of-windows-azure-websites-using-iis-manager/

Comment: this shows how to manage an azure Web Site with `local` IIS Manager. Which still will not show the Web Site's IIS version.

Answer (score -2):

Start > Admin tools > IIS Manager (NOT THE 6.0 MGR) > Help > About..:  voila

IIS is version 8.5.. on my windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: The question is asking about Azure Websites. There is no visible server or any RDP access available.